# ZMQ client does not recieve messages after converting to async

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a small client that I'm trying to get to communicate with a echo server I wrote, it's code is the following:

```py
import zmq


con = zmq.Context()

back: zmq.Socket = con.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
back.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"\x34")
back.connect("tcp://localhost:19802")

sock: zmq.Socket = con.socket(zmq.DEALER)
sock.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"\x35")
sock.connect("tcp://localhost:19801")


sock.send_multipart([b"1", b"2", b"3", b"4", b"5"])
msg = back.recv_multipart()
print(msg)
```

This works fine, and the client prints `[b'broker1', b'5', b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5']`. Then I wanted to see if I could do it with `zmq.async`. So I modified the code to the following:

```py
import zmq
import zmq.asyncio
import asyncio

con = zmq.asyncio.Context()

back: zmq.asyncio.Socket = con.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
back.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"\x34")
back.connect("tcp://localhost:19802")

sock: zmq.asyncio.Socket = con.socket(zmq.DEALER)
sock.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"\x35")
sock.connect("tcp://localhost:19801")

async def rcv():
    await sock.send_multipart([b"1", b"2", b"3", b"4", b"5"])
    msg = await back.recv_multipart()
    print(msg)

asyncio.run(rcv())
```

Now the server still receives `[b"5", b"1", b"2", b"3", b"4", b"5"]`. But the client hangs at `msg = await back.recv_multipart()`.

Why is this happening? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mentioned here https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1296. The problem is using `asyncio.run()` after creating globals attached to the existing loop. Changing `asyncio.run(rcv())` to:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(rcv())
```

works